# Word to describe something that makes you lose a bit of eagerness?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word to describe an aspect that mars the appearance/taste of something and **makes you lose eagerness?** Off-putting, maybe?

Example:

"*Wow this drink is tasty! How unfortunate that the appearance is so ______*"

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/off-putting

Answer (score 1):

A **buzzkill** is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/buzzkill) as

> A person or thing that has a depressing or dispiriting effect.

For the example given, one might say "How unfortunate that the appearance is such a buzzkill."

Answer (score 1):

A suitable word specific to the example context is ***unappetizing***.

> "Wow this drink is tasty! How unfortunate that the appearance is so
>   ***unappetizing***!"

ODO:

> **[unappetizing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unappetizing)** (*also* **unappetising**)
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Not inviting or attractive; unwholesome.
>
> ‘The first time he made it the soup looked so oxidised and grey and
>   unappetising, but the flavour was mind-blowing, like having 15
>   artichokes in every spoonful.

’

Answer (score 1):

***Debbie Downer*** as in:

*"I was so excited to go to the festival, but I found out that my favorite band wasn't playing.  What a Debbie Downer!"*

[image: Debbie Downer]

Answer (score 0):

Unappealing (adj): uninviting, unattractive, unsavory.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it caused some *discouragement* or was *discouraging*. You might say it *dampened* your spirit or eagerness.

You could say the appearance of the drink almost *deterred* you from consuming it.

Comment: Perhaps a turn-off.